# Passing a date value in JavaScript function converts as expression

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

If I send the date through the JavaScript function, it converts it as a expression automatically giving evaluation output.
e.g.: Suppose I give today's date "2018-06-30". It converts it showing the output "1982".
Can anyone please help me to pass the exact date through the JavaScript function.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="view" onClick="javascript:View('.$exp_date.')"/>

<script>
        function View(exp_date){
            phpurl="http://<?php echo($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) ?>/includes/functions.php?f=3&exp_date="+exp_date;
            $.ajax({                    
                url: phpurl,
                success: function(data){

                    $('#expenses_data').html(data);
                    $("#myModal").modal('show');            
                },
                complete: function(){

                    ajaxhide();

                },
                error: function(data){
                }                   
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Problem probably has nothing to do with javascript but rather whatever gets output in the html. Provide a  [mcve] that reproduces problem.

Comment: I checked with inspect its showing exactly date format 2018-06-30. I think problem is with javascript.

Comment: Oh. You are missing quotes around the date to represent it as string and not math expresssion

Comment: Take care in spelling JavaScript to avoid search collision with a Java.